# Zendesk - How do we can read data of currently opened tickets in server side app?

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

I have an app which is server side. my task is to read and display data from on currently opened tickets in my server side app.

is it possible? or what can be best solution for doing this?
Thanks

Comment: What is the location of the app in Zendesk? Is the url set to your app's entry point?

Comment: @ahmedsabriz location of zendesk app in sidebar. the url is hosted on another server. its server side app.

Comment: So you want to read and display ticket data in the ticket sidebar iframe?

Comment: yes. it need to display on sidebar iframe (server side app, no client side app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have set your app's entry point url in the manifest files as follows:

```
...
"location": {
  "support": {
    ticket_sidebar": {
      "url": "https://my.app/index.html"
    }
  }
},
...
```

You need to import [ZAF SDK](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/app-developer-guide/using-the-apps-framework/) into your app which will enable you to use the client to access ticket data. Refer to apps API [here](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/apps/apps-support-api/ticket_sidebar/).

Note that you will get an error on your server side app url because the ZAF client will only be defined within Zendesk. This is expected. So make sure you only test it on you Zendesk instance.

Refer to official tutorial [here](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/build-an-app/building-a-server-side-app/part-1-core-concepts/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, But the ZAF SDK didn't working on server side app

Comment: Many apps on the marketplace are server-side and utilise ZAF SDK including one app I built. Follow the tutorial I included and share any snippets where you get stuck.

Comment: I have already tried that, I'll try again with a fresh mind as well.

Comment: Now I got it. The ZAF SDK script execution will only be working when it runs through zendesk, it will not work if we tried to run outside zendesk/through URL. I was close but Thank you correcting me :)